# Personalized fanpage Tab

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to make a fanpage with the name and company of those who visit using PHP.

I managed to program it and add it to my page. But only appears if you have already added the the app before you visit.

I need to order installation of the app when the user enters the page.

how can i do this?

page http://www.facebook.com/pages/RMG-Direct/101016389955224?sk=app_246899652058808

Comment: You mean you want to add the tab as default when users go to your page?
That option has been disabled in Timeline for Pages.

Answer (score 0):

This stumped me for a while too when the made some changes back in December I believe. One solution I found helped me was to make a link on the page which creates a popup that lets you add the tab to a page.

```
<a href="#" onclick=window.open("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR APP ID HERE&next=YOUR APPS URL HERE","PageTab","width=800,height=500");>Add app to Your Page!</a>
```

and then refresh your browser & click it, and after you've added it to the page you can remove it again.